# Picard group of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^r\times\mathbb{P}^s$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, say $k=\mathbb{C}$. Let $r,s$ be sufficiently large integers.

Is it true that, for any irreducible hypersurface $X$ of bi-degree $(d,1)$ in $\mathbb{P}^r\times\mathbb{P}^r$, the Picard group $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ or the divisor class group $\mathrm{Cl}(X)$ equals to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$? I am not sure if the Lefschetz holds for such singular hypersurfaces?

Comment: A general hyperusrface of bidegree $(d,1)$ smooth. Are you really interested in singular (non-general) hypersurfaces?

Comment: @Sasha Yes, I am working on some problem which really needs the case for possibly singular hypersurfaces, thanks! By the Leray spectral sequence, it would be ok if codimension of locus whose Picard number greater than 1 has codimension at least two.

Comment: Codimension in the space of parameters? And I guess you mean Picard number greater than 2, right?

Comment: @Sasha Ah, sorry for my being imprecise.. If we consider the projection $\pi\colon\mathbb{P}^r\times\mathbb{P}^s\to\mathbb{P}^s$, then the restriction to $V(f)\to\mathbb{P}^s$ is a fibration in hypersurfaces. If we apply the Leray spectral sequence for the map, we want to delete a codimension 2 subvariety in $Z\subset V(f)$, so that $V(f)-Z\to\mathbb{P}^s-\pi(Z)$ is a fibration in constant Picard number 1. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand --- you want the result for any hypersurface, or for some hypersurfaces? Perhaps, it makes sense to edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: @Sasha It would be great if there’s result for any irreducible hypersurface, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this follows from Lazarsfeld positivity I, Example 3.1.25.

Comment: For $Pic(X)$ yes, but unless $X$ is factorial, I don't see how you can deduce it for $Cl(X)$. Beware that there are even nodal threefolds in $P^4$ where $Cl(X)\neq \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @WalterNeff Yes you are right, that shall not be true for class groups, thanks!

Comment: Following Lazarsfeld (the example you cited), for it is sufficient to have $r+s\ge 4$.